# How to find the minimum value from the ranges in array of hashes in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the below array of hashes

```
z = {"RANGE"=>[{"10-50"=>"5"}, {"50-100"=>"15"}, {"100-150"=>"25"}]}
```

How can I get output as 10

Comment: What exactly is posing a problem? Can we see what you attempted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
z["RANGE"].map(&:keys).flatten.map(&:to_i).min
#=> 10
```

[**Demo**](http://repl.it/xZ7/3)

Comment: you can do `x.to_i` without `split('-').first`

Answer (score 2):

```
z["RANGE"].map { |h| h.first.first.to_i }.min #=> 10
```

Alternatively, to avoid the construction of a temporary array:

```
z["RANGE"].min_by { |h| h.first.first.to_i }.first.first.to_i #=> 10
```

Note: `"10-50".to_i #=> 10`.

Postscript: considering how often one sees hashes having at most one key-value pair, perhaps we could use some `Hash` methods for working with them specifically. For example:

```
class Hash
  def only_key
    raise StandardError, "Hash has > 1 keys" if size > 1
    first.first
  end
  def only_value
    raise StandardError, "Hash has > 1 keys" if size > 1
    first.last
  end
end
```

We could then write:

```
z["RANGE"].map { |h| h.only_key.to_i }.min #=> 10
```

and if we wanted the smallest value:

```
z["RANGE"].map { |h| h.only_value.to_i }.min #=> 5
```